# Cannot get passwordless login ssh localhost, start-all.sh permision denied

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, hadoop, ssh

Ive been stuck on this issue for a couple days now. Im trying to setup hadoop locally as a pseudo distributed. Ive managed to install java and setup variables. But I am stuck on ssh localhost. I cannot get past the password request screen, and start-dfs.sh keeps giving me permission denied. Im assuming they are related?

```
fad@fad-System-Product-Name:~$ start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: fad@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Starting datanodes
localhost: fad@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Starting secondary namenodes [fad-System-Product-Name]
fad-System-Product-Name: fad@fad-system-product-name: Permission denied (publickey,password).
2019-03-06 21:05:52,321 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Assistance is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

give your username to super-user access then follow this

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
sudo su yourusername
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""
```

when it ask for details, just Press Enter

```
cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
```